# Cycle through columns and change value is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have the following table that is comparing two similar tables:

| Source | Part | Info 1 | Info 2 | ... | Info 12 | Description | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table 1 | Wheel | Circle |  | ... | Long Distance |  |  |
| Table 2 | Wheel | Circle | Rubber | ... | Long Distance | Wheel for vehicle | Black |
| Table 1 | Seat |  | 4 Seats | ... | Comfortable |  | Brown |
| Table 2 | Seat | Leather | 4 Seats | ... | Comfortable | Seat for vehicle | Brown |

I am trying to update the columns in Table 1 where it doesn't have the value of table 2.

I currently have the update query that works on a single field at one time but I am wondering if there is a way to make it dynamic and run through all the columns on a single run. Here is my working query right now:

```
UPDATE t
SET INFO2 = f.INFO2
FROM Table1 t
JOIN Table2 f ON f.PART = t.PART
WHERE t.INFO2 = '';
```

Comment: You could use a `CASE` expression, however, I really suggest you fix your design; it is heavily denormalised. Then the problem would be far easier.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here. But I suspect that if you normalized your design your update would become super easy.

Comment: `SET INFO2 =  f.INFO2,  INFO3 =  f.INFO3, ..`

Comment: @Serg Can I do that, but then also in my WHERE do INFO2 = '' AND INFO3 = '' ..?  I feel as though that wont update the right entry but only the ones where the rules are follow and all columns are empty

Comment: @SeanLange I am trying to update the table 1 entries where they are null with the value from table 2

Comment: Are they NULL or empty strings? You say NULL but your code is an empty string. Those are not the same thing. Either way using a case expression as already stated is likely what you are going to need here.

Comment: they are empty strings. I am not a sql developer, so empty is null to me so I apologize for the confusion. But if you can explain how I would use a CASE statement, that would actually be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CASE expression to update NULL / empty string column, leave it as it is otherwise

```
UPDATE t
  SET INFO2 = case when coalesce(t.INFO2, '') = '' then f.INFO2 else t.INFO2 end, 
      INFO3 = case when coalesce(t.INFO3, '') = '' then f.INFO3 else t.INFO3 end, ..
FROM Table1 t
JOIN Table2 f ON f.PART = t.PART ;
```